# How do you solve CSS Background IMG

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, html5-canvas, html5-video

I want this background IMG needed in the left-touch corner. here is this code I am trying to solve but am not able to do.

```
#Bg,img{
width: 150px;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
float: left;
}
```

[Img Hexa background for nav](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6EkD.png)

Comment: Please add some sample HTML on your post, and create some example concept images to show what you would like to achieve, for clarity.

Comment: **(1)** That code doesn't do anything, it is not complete. You need an `<image>` tag to display the image you call _"Img Hexa background for nav"_.  You need associate a CSS class with the tag. **(2)** Look at [this example code](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_image_test). Add your CSS there and then [update your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74735614/edit) with **complete testable code for recreating the problem**.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code:

```
#Bg,img{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0%;
    bottom: 0%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        img {
            height: 500px;
            width: 800px;
            margin: 0%;
            padding-top: 150px;
            float: left;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

<img src="../IMG20210906184852-01.jpg" alt="">

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try "position: absolute;" instead of "float: left;"

```
#Bg,img { 
top: 0% 
left: 0% 
position: absolute; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming this is for a logo at the top left corner.
If you have a universal reset at the top of your CSS, when you add your image to the HTML, it should show up at the top left.

`* {margin: 0;padding: 0;box-sizing: border-box;}`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).